# Sorting tuples with a custom sorting function using a range?

Tags: python, sorting, tuples, custom-function

I would like to sort a list of tuples based on the two last columns:

```
mylist = [(33, 36, 84), 
          (34, 37, 656), 
          (23, 38, 42)]
```

I know  I can do this like:

```
final = sorted(mylist, key:lambda x: [ x[1], x[2]])
```

Now my problem is that I want to compare the second column of my list with a special condition: if the difference between two numbers is less than an offset  they should be taken as equal ( 36 == 37 == 38) and the third column should be used to sort the list. The end result I wish to see is:

```
mylist = [(23, 38, 42)
          (33, 36, 84), 
          (34, 37, 656)]
```

I was thinking of creating my own integer type and overriding the equal operator. Is this possible? is it overkill? Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by offset. Do not make your own type though, you can make the lambda function more complex. Make it compute a single number out of the two last numbers of the tuple that will take all this into account.

Comment: By an offset I mean a small number. For instance 
if offset = 2 then (36 + offset) == 38

Comment: I'll post, but this breaks the transitive property. Be careful where you use this comparison.

Comment: What happens if you have [(1,6),
(2,5),
(3,4),
(4,3),
(5,2),
(6,1)] with offset 1?

Comment: In that case the second column would be used for sorting. The first one would be ignored if the offset  > 1.

Comment: Doing what you want can't be done using the `key` argument on `sorted` because the function you pass there has one parameter and is called exactly once for each element of the collection you want to sort. Thus it only deals with one element at a time.

If you overwrite the equal operator in the way you proposed, you end up with a sorted list that depends on the sorting algorithm which I am not sure is what you want either.

Comment: But for example the first item (1,6) is not withing the offset with item (3,4), so the (1,6) should be before (3,4), because we are sorting by the first item. But if you take that 1 == 2 == 3, then they should be sorted by the second item and (3,4) should come before (1,6). This is ambiguous. You need to make a more precise definition.

Comment: I did not think about this problem before. Will consider it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to create a new class that compares like you want it to:

```
mylist = [(33, 36, 84), 
          (34, 37, 656), 
          (23, 38, 42)]

offset = 2

class Comp(object):
    def __init__(self, tup):
        self.tup = tup

    def __lt__(self, other):  # sorted works even if only __lt__ is implemented.
        # If the difference is less or equal the offset of the second item compare the third
        if abs(self.tup[1] - other.tup[1]) <= offset:
            return self.tup[2] < other.tup[2]
        # otherwise compare them as usual
        else:
            return (self.tup[1], self.tup[2]) < (other.tup[1], other.tup[2])
```

A sample run shows your expected result:

```
>>> sorted(mylist, key=Comp)
[(23, 38, 42), (33, 36, 84), (34, 37, 656)]
```

---

I think it's a bit cleaner than using `functools.cmp_to_key` but that's a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes an old-style sort based on a `cmp` function is easier than doing one based on a `key`. So -- write a `cmp` function and then use `functools.cmp_to_key` to convert it to a key:

```
import functools

def compare(s,t,offset):
    _,y,z = s
    _,u,v = t
    if abs(y-u) > offset: #use 2nd component
        if y < u:
            return -1
        else:
            return 1
    else: #use 3rd component
        if z < v:
            return -1
        elif z == v:
            return 0
        else:
            return 1

mylist = [(33, 36, 84), 
          (34, 37, 656), 
          (23, 38, 42)]

mylist.sort(key = functools.cmp_to_key(lambda s,t: compare(s,t,2)))

for t in mylist: print(t)
```

output:

```
(23, 38, 42)
(33, 36, 84)
(34, 37, 656)
```

Answer (score 1):

In https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting look for "The Old Way Using the cmp Parameter". This allows you to write your own comparison function, instead of just setting the key and using comparison operators.

There is a danger to making a sort ordering like this. Look up "strict weak ordering." You could have multiple different valid orderings. This can break other code which assumes there is one correct way to sort things.

Now to actually answer your question:

```
mylist = [(33, 36, 84), 
          (34, 37, 656), 
          (23, 38, 42)]

def custom_sort_term(x, y, offset = 2):
    if abs(x-y) <= offset:
        return 0
    return x-y

def custom_sort_function(x, y):
    x1 = x[1]
    y1 = y[1]
    first_comparison_result = custom_sort_term(x1, y1)
    if (first_comparison_result):
        return first_comparison_result
    x2 = x[2]
    y2 = y[2]
    return custom_sort_term(x2, y2)

final = sorted(mylist, cmp=custom_sort_function)
print final
```

> [(23, 38, 42), (33, 36, 84), (34, 37, 656)]

Comment: only works in python 2. In python 3 the cmp parameter is gone.

Comment: Bummer, but it looks like there are plenty of other ways to do the same the same thing if OP is on python3. I'll leave this here since nobody else mentioned that his sort violates strict weak ordering (probably not a deal breaker but needs to be considered).

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty, but I tried be general in my interpretation of OP's problem statement

I expanded test case, then applied unsophisticated blunt force

```
# test case expanded
mylist = [(33, 6, 104),
          (31, 36, 84),
          (35, 86, 84),
          (30, 9, 4),
          (23, 38, 42),
          (34, 37, 656),          
          (33, 88, 8)]

threshld = 2    # different final output can be seen if changed to 1, 3, 30

def collapse(nums, threshld):
    """
    takes sorted (increasing) list of numbers, nums
    replaces runs of consequetive nums
    that successively differ by threshld or less
    with 1st number in each run
    """
    cnums = nums[:]
    cur = nums[0]
    for i in range(len(nums)-1):
        if (nums[i+1] - nums[i]) <= threshld:
            cnums[i+1] = cur
        else:
            cur = cnums[i+1]
    return cnums

mylists = [list(i) for i in mylist] # change the tuples to lists to modify

indxd=[e + [i] for i, e in enumerate(mylists)] # append the original indexing    
#print(*indxd, sep='\n')
im0 = sorted(indxd, key=lambda x: [ x[1]])      # sort by  middle number   
cns = collapse([i[1] for i in im0], threshld)   # then collapse()
#print(cns)
for i in range(len(im0)):                       # overwrite collapsed into im0
    im0[i][1] = cns[i]   
#print(*im0, sep='\n')
im1 = sorted(im0, key=lambda x: [ x[1], x[2]])  # now do 2 level sort
#print(*sorted(im0, key=lambda x: [ x[1], x[2]]), sep='\n')
final = [mylist[im1[i][3]] for i in range(len(im1))] # rebuid using new order 
                                                     # of original indices       
print(*final, sep='\n')

(33, 6, 104)
(30, 9, 4)
(23, 38, 42)
(31, 36, 84)
(34, 37, 656)
(33, 88, 8)
(35, 86, 84)
```